# Emberjs Stripe integration post with stripeToken

Tags: ember.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe into my Ember app and I'm running into a snag when the initial card collection post is finished. Stripe tries to post the form surrounding the

```
<form {{action "charge" on="submit"}} method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="plan" {{bind-attr value="plan.id"}} />
  {{strip-button amount=plan.amount name=plan.name emailAddress=emailAddress}}
</form>
```

The problem is that I do not want to do not want to do a server `POST`. I would like to take hijack the form `POST` and do my own custom post of the stripeToken and other data elements to actually create the charge.

StripeButton component below:

```
var StripeButton = Ember.Component.extend({
    scriptSource: '<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"',
    scriptClose: '></script>',
    dataElement: function(element, value) {
        return 'data-' + element + '="' + value + '"';
    },
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().append(
            this.get('scriptSource') +
            this.dataElement('key', 'pk_test_wat') +
            this.dataElement('amount', this.get('amount')) +
            this.dataElement('email', this.get('emailAddress')) +
            this.dataElement('label', this.get('name') + ' Plan') +
            this.dataElement('name', 'Company Name') +
            this.dataElement('description', this.get('name')) +
            this.get('scriptClose')
      );
    }
});

export default StripeButton;
```

How do I tell Ember to take control of the form submit with my own action to perform the custom ajax I need?

Comment: Was concocting a cool solution for you, but for some reason I couldn't intercept the submit event from checkout.js:  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yiguselade/5/edit .  In any case, I think this looks pretty close to the solution...

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll continue to play with it to see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the `checkout.js` custom integration here: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

This will allow you greater flexibility in creating your solution instead of trying to hack the simple integration.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. We would like to stay away from ever "collecting" the CC information. Using the stripe form and not implementing our own is the preferred method at this point. Thanks!

Comment: The implementation should look the same, it just allows you to use a custom button and provide a `token` callback for when the `StripeCheckout` handler is complete.  The form itself should be unaltered.